# Samsung Smart TV Device Name access

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, television

Is it possible to get **access to the device name** of the Smart TV in my application? 
I can get access pushing `Menu -> Network -> Device Name` on the remote, but I need to get this name and change it with **javascript** in my application.

Comment: Have a look: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00008/nservice/dtv_nservice_device.html